Shortening UnderBraces by given lengths in nicematrix

\UnderBrace in nicematrix has a key shorten, to reduce the width on left and right by around 5.72pt, but it does not throw an error when specifying a custom length shorten=<length> nor does it respond by shortening to the required <length>
My MWE
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}, hvlines}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{r p[c]{4cm}}
    
    Text 1
    & Text 1a
    \\
    \addlinespace[1ex]
    
    & description 1a
    \\
    \addlinespace
    
    \CodeAfter
    \UnderBrace[shorten=\linewidth]{1-2}{1-2}{}
    
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


Page 39 of the manual says "left-shorten and right-shorten which do not take in value"  https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf

By design, the keys left-shorten, right-shorten and shorten do not take in a value (nevertheless, I should have raised an error message when these keys are used with a value).
By design, the key shorten will compute the length of the brace by taking into account the contents of the cells involved by the command.
In the following example, I have added a light background for the cells involved by the command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{ccc}
  one & two words & three other words \\
  four & \Block[fill=gray!10,transparent]{2-2}{} five & six \\
  seven & eight & nine
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[shorten]{2-2}{3-3}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


In the following example, I have changed the involved cells (by using \UnderBrace[shorten]{1-2}{3-3} instead of \UnderBrace[shorten]{2-2}{3-3}).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{ccc}
  one & \Block[fill=gray!10,transparent]{3-2}{} two words & three other words \\
  four & five & six \\
  seven & eight & nine
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[shorten]{1-2}{3-3}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



However, there is a complication. When I say the "content of the cell", I mean : the PGF/TikZ node created by nicematrix under the cell (as available with the syntax i-j in the \CodeBefore and the \CodeAfter). For a cell in a column of type p, this node has a width equal to the width of the column (because such cell is meant to contain a wrapped paragraph with a width equal to the value set as argument of  p).
In the following example, the brace is not shortened because of the columns p{4cm}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{cp{4cm}p{4cm}}
  one & two words & three other words \\
  four & \Block[fill=gray!10,transparent]{2-2}{} five & six \\
  seven & eight & nine
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[shorten]{2-2}{3-3}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


But that example is probably a misuse of the columns p (why using a column of type p for short elements which are not multi-lines?).
It would be more pertinent to use columns of type w{c}{...}.
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{cw{c}{4cm}w{c}{4cm}}
  one & two words & three other words \\
  four & \Block[fill=gray!10,transparent]{2-2}{} five & six \\
  seven & eight & nine
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[shorten]{2-2}{3-3}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


It's also possible to use the columns V of varwidth (when varwidth is loaded). Then, it's still possible to put multi-lines paragraphs is some cells.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,varwidth}

\NiceMatrixOptions{rules/color=[gray]{0.75}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{cV[c]{4cm}V[c]{4cm}}
  one & two words & a small paragraph with several lines of text\\
  four & \Block[fill=gray!10,transparent]{2-2}{} five & six \\
  seven & eight & nine
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[shorten]{2-2}{3-3}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



Even tough the key left-shorten, right-shorten and shorten of the commands \Underbrace and \Overbrace does not take in a value (by design), it might be a good idea to add that possibility in a future version of nicematrix. That value would be used to shorten the brace in an absolute way...
